# Spring Data multiple data sources one schema

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, multi-tenant

I have 1 domain model and two different data sources. Also I need automatic schema generation on start-up (not possible with hiberante multi tenancy) and I cannot use RoutingDatasource, since I need to explicitly choose the data base on calling the repository.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "FranceEntityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef = "FranceTransactionManager",
basePackageClasses = {FooRepositoryFrance.class})
public class FranceDbConfig
{
   @Bean
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "france.datasource")
   public HikariDataSource FranceDataSource()
   {
      // init dataSource, transactionManager and EnityManagerFactory...
   }
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "SpainEntityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef = "SpainTransactionManager",
basePackageClasses = {FooRepositorySpain.class})
public class SpainDbConfig
{
   @Bean
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spain.datasource")
   public HikariDataSource SpainDataSource()
   {
      // init dataSource, transactionManager and EnityManagerFactory...
   }
}

@Entity
public class Foo 
{
   // code ...
}

@Transactional("FranceTransactionManager")
public class FooRepositoryFrance extends CrudRepository...

@Transactional("SpainTransactionManager")
public class FooRepositorySpain extends CrudRepository...
```

No matter with data source I try to choose with @Transactional("...") it always used the data source that was inititalized and the entities are accessible with both repositories.

Answer (score 0):

May be i am answering pretty late but here you go.

1. I need automatic schema generation on start-up - **not recommended in production never** .Workaround use single db and then hibernate will generate schema for for you or use a embedded db (such as H2) that will generate schema creations commands on console.
2. multi tenancy can be done in different ways i don't know your exact business case but here you go - **1.separating databases, 2.separating schemas, or 3.sharing schemas.**
   1 and 2 are mostly used.
   (https://dzone.com/articles/multi-tenancy-using-jpa-spring-and-hibernate-part)
   (https://dzone.com/articles/multi-tenancy-using-jpa-spring-and-hibernate-part-2)

   I cannot use RoutingDatasource, since I need to explicitly choose the data base on calling the repository. - choose option 2.